# How to Fetch and display the json data values using python beautiful Soup

Tags: jquery, python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am in a big dilemma. I am using python beautiful soup for web scraping.
    I am a beginner to python web scraping. I am trying to fetch the json values from jQuery Variable.

Please see the code:

---

```
import requests
import re
import json
import sys
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
url = 'http://foodie.inhouse.net/'
response = requests.get(url)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
matchObject = re.search(r'myList = {"Today":(.*),"Tomorrow"',html)
print matchObject.groups()
```

---

Now the output i am getting is:

---

```
('{"1":{"egg":0,"chicken":0,"fish":0,"veg":1,"stamp":"2017-05-03","value":"Idli, Chammanthi, Vendakka Sambar","custom":"idli.jpg"},"2":{"egg":0,"chicken":0,"fish":0,"veg":1,"stamp":"2017-05-03","value":"Rice, sambar, aviyal, ulli thoran, pappad, pickle, curd.","custom":"rice.jpg"},"3":{"egg":0,"chicken":0,"fish":0,"veg":1,"stamp":"2017-05-03","value":"paripuvada","custom":"ada.jpg"},"4":{"egg":0,"chicken":1,"fish":0,"veg":1,"stamp":"2017-05-03","value":"Rice, Vellarikka Curry, Olan, Chicken thoran, Mushroom Stir fry","custom":"rice.jpg"},"5":{"egg":0,"chicken":0,"fish":0,"veg":1,"stamp":"2017-05-03","value":"Puttu, pazham","custom":"puttu.jpg"}}',)
```

---

What i want is like this:
Morning: Idli, Chammanthi, Vendakka Sambar
Lunch: Rice, sambar, aviyal, ulli thoran, pappad, pickle, curd
Evening: paripuvada

etc...

Comment: Looks like a http://foodie.inhouse.net/ is not a valid domain. Can you share the right domain with us?

Comment: Actually the domain "foodie.inhouse.net" is restricted to my organization. Nobody can access the website from outside. I need the solution for parsing the json data.

Comment: did you try running `json.loads(result[0])` ?

Comment: I tried:But this is what i am getting                                                 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 35, in <module>
    json.loads(matchObject[0])
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'                           code                                                                            f          matchObject = re.search(r'autoList = [{"category":(.*)]', html)
json.loads(matchObject[0])
print matchObject.groups()

Comment: You need to do `json.loads(matchObject.groups()[0])` instead of `json.loads(matchObject[0])`

Comment: Yes.. I did its just printing 135423 in newline

Comment: Can you add the HTML content to your question?

Comment: Is viewpage source content enough?? I will add the view page source content

Comment: Hello please click on the link to see the code:  https://pastebin.com/qY2Uh55K

Comment: Checkout the code for using `json.loads` [here](https://pastebin.com/Udzmaqhv)

Comment: Thanks: But what i want is like this: means i need to fetch only values:      Morning: Upumavu, kadala curry, pazham,pappad   Lunch: Rice, toamto curry, payar thoran, kozhuva fry, veg: potato fry  Evening: Ada  Night: Rice, Ulli Sambar, Kadala Thoran, Kovaikka Mezhukkupuratty, Pickle, Pappad   I need your help for this. Also I need to send these contents as sms. It would be helpful if  tou know how to send sms via twilio or way2sms. I think its pprint. thanks.